Measurement invariance and latent mean comparison between 3 groups
I performed an Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA) followed by a Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA) in R, successfully assessing the model fit using indices such as TLI, CFI, RMSEA for a two-factor structure. Subsequently, I categorized my data into three distinct groups. I then ensured measurement invariance across these groups, achieving configural, metric, and scalar invariance.
For the final analysis phase, I aim to compare the latent means of the two factors across these groups. For instance, I am interested in determining whether Factor 1 is statistically higher in Group 2 compared to Group 3.
My questions are: How should I proceed to compare the latent means across two factors and three groups? Moreover, in making these comparisons, should I base them on the scalar model or the configural model?
This is my Code:
Fitted model:
odelCFA3_3 <- '
  PTSD_stigma_Factor1 =~  PTperstigma_3 + PTperstigma_2
  
  PTSD_stigma_Factor2 =~ PTperstigma_9 + PTperstigma_8 + PTperstigma_6
  '

fit <- cfa(modelCFA3_3, data = CFA, missing = 'ML')
summary(fit,fit.measures = TRUE, standardized=T)

and for example:
fitConfigural_PTSD <- cfa(modelCFA3_3, data = mydata, missing = "ML", group = "Sample_Group")
summary(fitConfigural_PTSD, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)



How should I proceed to compare the latent means across two factors and three groups?

If you are setting group.equal = c("loadings","intercepts"), then by default, lavaan identifies the scalar-invariance model by fixing the first group's latent means to 0, estimating the other group means.  So the mean for Group 2 (and 3) is already its difference from Group 1; thus, you can look at the Wald z test in the summary() to test the $H_0$ that the difference is 0.  To test a difference between Groups 2 and 3, juts label those means in your syntax, and define a parameter that is the difference between each mean across groups 2 and 3.

should I base them on the scalar model or the configural model?

Without constraining loadings and intercepts, the latent-variable locations/scales are not linked, so comparisons are meaningless.  That is why (at least partial) scalar-invariance constraints are necessary.
